# React-Native duplicate component name

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native` with `native-base` theme. Now I want to use `react-native-share` package. But I need to use Button from both package but I got duplicate identifier error.

```
import Share, { ShareSheet, Button } from 'react-native-share';
import { Button } from 'native-base';
```

May I know how to declare another button from `react-native-share`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try use:

```
Import { Button as Btn } from 'native-base'
```

This should resolve your problem.